# How to save objects in spring data with breadth-first instead of depth-first?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, recursion, spring-data

I have a StackOverflow error when saving an object with a big recursive structure in Spring Data/Hibernate.

The structure with recursion is more or less like:

```
Schedule -> Contents -> Teachers -> Schedules
```

Schedule class has:

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
public List<Content> getContents() {
...
}
```

Content class has:

```
@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
public List<Teacher> getTeachers() {
 ...
}
```

And teacher has:

```
@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn (nullable = true)
public Schedule getSchedule() {
...
}
```

And to save it I use:

```
this.scheduleRepository.save(schedule);
```

Where `this.scheduleRepository` is a `CrudRepository`.

When is a small schedule, it is saved without problems. But when it is a big schedule (with lots of teachers, it throws a StackOverflow exception.

I know that it isn't an infinite recursion because it doesn't recurse when it has already "check" an element and the problem is because it has so many elements that the depth is too big for the stack memory.

I also know that I can increase the stack memory with `-Xss4096k` but I don't know how big will be the future schedules. The solution I might do is manually saving individuals, and then the global object manually (basically break the recursion and do it manually).

However, if Hibernate saved it in a breadth-first fashion instead of depth-first it won't use too much stack memory as there will be only 3 levels of recursion. But I don't know if it is possible.

**So my question is if it is possible to configure Spring-data/JPA/Hibernate to save an object cascade all in a breadth-first fashion instead of depth-first.**

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is

`@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.MERGE)` or 
`@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)`

Comment: Sorry but no, using that kind of cascade is the same when you don't have the object already in the database.